# Deploying an Recording Instrument in a 3 - 5 m hole

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I am trying to think of the best way to deploy an instrument in a 3 - 5 m posthole.
The instrument is approximately 15 kg, and it shouldn't be dropped into the hole.  The tricky bit is that the instrument needs to be kept vertical when being lowered into the posthole.  The posthole looks similar to the attached image.

I am thinking about using some sort of hook to attach to the handle to lower it down, but I'm wondering if you all have any ideas about the best way to keep the instrument stable, is not at risk of falling off the hook, and the hook can be removed when the instrument reaches the bottom of the hole. Any ideas would be appreciated!

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

I would just loop a rope through the handle, then keep hold of one end and let the other end slide through to drop the item down.

Then, as there is no knot the rope can be pulled through and removed completely.

Getting it out may, of course, be a challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Having a single eye hole/loop/bolt at the top of the probe, in the center, would allow the use of a single rope to lower the probe vertically. Alternatively, having two such eye loop/bolt on opposite side of the probe would allow the use of two ropes.

If such modifications are not possible I would attach two ropes to the flat section of the handle and lower the probe vertically with two ropes.